# Mailchimp - Conditional Merge tage to compare dates

Tags: java, spring, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to compare two dates using mailchimp merge tags
where both dates are not getting compare. 
kindly provide solution

```
 *|IF:COMP_DATE=2016-06-06|* 
 *|COMP_DATE|* is your completion date. 
 *|END:IF|*
```

where  COMP_DATE has already stored value is  06-06-2016